# Issue in finding time difference

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my app, I want to know the difference between:

> the total hours worked in the week(54.30 hours)

and

> the total hours worked on a specific day(10.45 hours)

For example, I want to know the value of (54.30 hours - 10.45 hours) in
hours. Since the total hours of week is greater than 24 hrs, I
couldn't convert it into NSDate.

Comment: Did you tried anything ?

Comment: `54.30` means 54 hours and 30 minutes, or 54 hours and 0.3*60 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Use this 2 functions,this will help you

The below function will return total seconds from the hour string

```
- (NSNumber *)secondsForTimeString:(NSString *)string {
    NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSInteger hours   = [[components objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
    NSInteger minutes = [[components objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
    //NSInteger seconds = [[components objectAtIndex:2] integerValue];
   return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60)];
```

}

And below function will return formatted time from seconds

```
- (NSString *)timeFormatted:(int)totalSeconds {
    //int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
    int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d.%02d",hours, minutes];
}
```

Now you can calculate the remaining hours like this :

```
int diffrence =[[self secondsForTimeString:@"54.30"] intValue] - [[self secondsForTimeString:@"10.45"] intValue];
NSLog(@"Remaining Hours - %@",[self timeFormatted:diffrence]);
```